# Spark SQL "<=>" operator

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I recently came across this operator: "<=>" in a Scala Spark project.
I am having trouble finding any documentation on it. Does any know how it works, or know of some documentation?

I believe it has something to with equality operations.

Thanks

**Observation 1 (2/12/2020) | Spark 2.3.2**
I have done some experimentation and noticed that performing joins on co-located data with "<=>" causes a shuffle to happen, while "==" does not.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Checkout the Section "Supported Hive Feature on Spark SQL Programming guide [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html) and you will find it in the list of Hive Operators supported by Spark.

Here is what it does:

- Returns same result with EQUAL(=) operator for non-null operands

however:

- it returns TRUE if both are NULL
- it returns FALSE if one of them is NULL

Answer (score -2):

Does this work in the join condition . i used it but spark throws an error

```
spark.sql('''
select tp1.* from tp1 left join tp2 where tp1.user_id_num <=> tp2.user_id_num''').show()
```

Error that i get

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Detected implicit cartesian product for LEFT OUTER join between logical plans
```

Comment: your query is mixing up explicit (left join) and implicit join (where id=id)