# Clarification on usage of spark dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 3 dataframes 'u', 'join5' and site.

Here is the schema of dataframe 'u'.

```
scala> println(u.printSchema)
root
 |-- split_sk: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- new_date: string (nullable = true)
```

Now creating join6 with joining 'join5' and 'site' dataframes. Here are my 2 questions -

- What is 'u("split_sk")' here in the below query?  Is this possible to use the column of dataframe 'u' to compare randomly when join with 'u' is not clearly given in query?
- What (<=>) sign represents to in scala and in particular in below query?

```
val join6 = join5.join(site, u("split_sk") <=> site("split_key") &&($"new_date" >= $"effective_dt") && ($"new_date" <=  $"expiry_dt"),"left")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1,

Yes, "split_sk" is the column in "u". This is similar to SQL, `a.column1 = b.column2`. It is spark way of specifying the same as above.

To answer another question, Yes it is possible to specify some column of a dataframe that is not present in the query. Most likely the scenario is join5 dataframe is created on top of join5

For question 2,

`<=>` is called NULL SAFE join.
Refer to this [Spark SQL "<=>" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41469327/spark-sql-operator)

Comment: Thanks. And what is it doing in below - This new_date in below query is of which dataframe - u/join5/site? I hope it is of join5.


val join6 = join5.join(site, u("split_sk") <=> site("split_key") &&($"new_date" >= $"effective_dt") && ($"new_date" <=  $"expiry_dt"),"left")

Comment: Updated my comment above.

Comment: It is like a conditional join, like "join when split_sk is equal to split_key and other conditions about date are satisfied"

Comment: Yes, so dates from which and which dataframe? new_date of u/join5/site dataframe joining with effective date of which dataframe? Dataframe 'u' has created the confusion here for me by jumping in between. However, I think comparision of dates is between join5 and site dataframes. Please confirm.

Comment: Provide the printSchema for all the dataframes